# Passing Type to C macros

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a type in C macro, But I am getting error.

```
#include <stdio.h>)

    int size = 0;
    #define SIZEOF(TYPE) \
        TYPE _array_[2]; \
        size = (char*)(&_array_[1]) - (char*)(&_array_[0]);

    int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {
        int array[2];
        int x = SIZEOF(int);
        printf("Size Of Integer = %d", SIZEOF(int));
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Did you notice you accidentally posted the same question twice?

Comment: It returns -ECANTPARSE

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Type in a C macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245696/passing-type-in-a-c-macro)

Comment: I know this isn't the answer to the question you asked, but I feel like I should just mention that `sizeof` exists.

Comment: The reason for a question to be a duplicate is that it "has been asked before and already has an answer", meaning that both of your questions are now duplicates as they both have an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Macro expansion is a text replacement. Your code expands to:

```
int x = int _array_[2]; size = (char*)(&_array_[1]) - (char*)(&_array_[0]);
```

The initial part `int x = int` is a syntax error.

You could make your code work without changing the macro by writing:

```
SIZEOF(int);
printf("Size Of Integer = %d", size);
```

An improvement would be to pass the name of the variable as a parameter to the macro, instead of using global variables.

Comment: compilers in pre-ansi c days used a macro that did, IIRC:  (int)(&((TYPE*)0)[1]))  or similar. Basically, cast 0 to a pointer of TYPE and find the address of [1], then cast that address back to a number.  Of course, Not needed now all interesting compilers have sizeof

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define SIZEOF(TYPE) \
    ({ \
    TYPE _array_[2]; \
    (char*)(&_array_[1]) - (char*)(&_array_[0]); \
    })
```

...although it uses gcc specific support for statements inside expressions, so I would recommend using the standard `sizeof` operator instead.

How to actually use this:

```
printf("Size Of Integer = %d", (int)SIZEOF(int));
```

i.e. it works as a pretty good replacement for `sizeof` on compilers that actually allow the dirty trick of statements inside expressions.